# No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'VarHandleOp' with these attrs. Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels: <no registered kernels>

Tags: python, android, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am deploying my custom build tensorflow image classification model (.pb format) in Android Device. It takes the image but then it throws exception in run method and says: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'VarHandleOp' with these attrs.  Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels:

```
 [[{{node conv2d/kernel}} = VarHandleOp[_class=["loc:@conv2d/kernel"], container="", dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[3,3,1,64], shared_name="conv2d/kernel"]()]]
```

I am following the [samuel13b/AndroidTensorflowTutorial](https://github.com/samuel13b/AndroidTensorflowTutorial/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/samuel/smartgallery/smartgallery) link where I just replace my model with respective parameters

Comment: Do you have any layers/activations/regularizers etc not officially a part of `tf.keras`?

Comment: my model contains the following details:

0 dense layers
64 layer size
3 conv layers

in that the model is 

m = Sequential()
Conv2D(layer_size, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:])
Activation('relu')
MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))
for l in range(conv_layer-1):
Conv2D(layer_size, (3, 3))
Activation('relu')
MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))
Flatten()
for _ in range(dense_layer):
Dense(layer_size)
Activation('relu')
Dense(1)
Activation('sigmoid')